# executing rsync from local that ssh to remote and copys to secondary remote

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, rsync

Ok, so what I am trying to do is have a script(s) that I execute from local(1) that ssh into remote(1) and rsync /path/to/file to remote(2) /path/to/file

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set oldIP "[lrange $argv 0 0]"
set newIP "[lrange $argv 1 1]"

set password "123..."
set admin "User"
set host localhost


spawn ssh '$admin'@'$oldIP' 
expect -exact "Password: "  
sleep 3
send -- "$password\r" 
expect -exact "$host:~ user# " 
send -- "rsync -azvH --numeric-ids -W --force /path/ '$newIP':/path/"
expect -exact "Password: "  
sleep 3
send -- "$password\r"
sleep 1
send -- quit\n"
```

Comment: If you were using RSA key authentication rather than passwords, you wouldn't need `expect` for this *at all* -- it would just be `ssh -A admin@host1 "rsync -azvH --numeric-ids -W --force /path host2:/path"` (mostly; escaping the hostnames to be robust against shell injection attempts is a separate issue, but one we already cover here). The `-A` enables agent forwarding, so a key stored in your local agent could be used by the remote `rsync` to authenticate to the final destination host.

Comment: (Your last send is missing a `"`). You need to add a final `interact` or similar to wait until the rsync is finished, or you will close the ssh connection too soon.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you instead of using expect command better to create password less login from remote 1 server to remote 2 server and then setup a cron job which would do it automatically.

You can refer to this below link on how to setup password less login :

https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: I could and probably do it in the future but what I am trying to do will not involve a constant need. These are not servers, I am just trying to get some of the /Users/ information from there current machine and transfer it to there new machine.

Comment: Try to execute your script in debugging mode. Hope you might find some clues.